# Monitor Apache Aurora Observer resources usage

Tags: python, mesos, apache-aurora

I've been using `Mesos` to run tasks via aurora on vagrant.

I need to monitor the resources the tasks are really using (not the resources fixed per aurora configuration) which are actually showed in the Observe, but I haven't found any Endpoints to do it.

Aurora provides [this python library](https://github.com/apache/aurora/tree/master/src/main/python), 
but I don't really know how to use it.

So, has anyone got the same problem? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So... if someone is interested in, there i sa way to done it "real time".
You can access via http endpoints like that :

http://ip:port(usually 1338)/processes?task_id='task_id'